# User conversation Logic Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm building a small message system that will show a thread of messages between only two users. For the most part I've got this working and the messages displayed in the correct order etc. However the problem I'm having now is that conversations with different users all look the same.

I've narrowed it down to a problem with the where clause logic I'm using when trying to retrieve a thread between two users. I've tried different combinations of logic, but some mean I've got too many messages and other mean I've got too few. I just can't figure out the right combination to get the full thread for just the two users.

```
// Get all conversations logged in user sent or received
List<GetConversation> Conversation =
    KoData.GetConversations
    .Where(c => (c.Recipient == recipient || c.Sender == LoggedInUser) || (c.Sender == recipient || c.Recipient == LoggedInUser))
    .OrderBy(c => c.MessageTime)
    .ToList();
```

Recipient in this case is the user the logged in user is in conversation with (I know it's a bit confusing and I plan to simplify it when it's all up and working).

Can anyone help with the right where clause logic? Or if there's more to it than that and there's something I'm missing and someone could advise me that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried this?
`.Where(c => (c.Recipient == recipient && c.Sender == LoggedInUser) || (c.Sender == recipient && c.Recipient == LoggedInUser))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it gets confusing but in this case I'm pretty sure it's:

`.Where(c => (c.Recipient == recipient && c.Sender == LoggedInUser) || (c.Sender == recipient && c.Recipient == LoggedInUser))`

Spelled out it's basically "either to him/her and from me, or to me and from him/her"